Changes to Django-Parler aren't applied
I'm working on my Django project, and currently I'm incorporating translations and localization, and I have an issue.
I used to have the default language as English, but now I want it to be Spanish, but for some reason it's still English. Also, with Django-Parler, I can see on the English side of  the website with Spanish content,  even I  thought already selected 'hide_untranslated': True, . Why are changes not applied?
# languages
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'

LANGUAGES = [
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('ar', _('Arabic')),
    ('tr', _('Turkish')),
]

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'locale',
]

PARLER_LANGUAGES = {
    1: (
        {'code': 'es',}, # Spanish
        {'code': 'en',}, # English
        {'code': 'ar',}, # Arabic
        {'code': 'tr',}, # Turkish
    ),
    'default': {
        'fallbacks': ['es'],
        'hide_untranslated': True,  
    }
}

